# when to use moustache.js or backbone.js

Tags: json, api, rest, backbone.js, mustache

I'm wondering when it is useful to use moustache.js (or something similar which do js templating), and when I can use backbone.js (which uses js templating inside it)

I've a web app with multiple pages, a json app, and the pages data are loaded via api calls, so I've tought about using moustache to clean up the rendering, but I'm wondering if backbone will improve something in my case

Comment: They serve two very different purposes: Mustache is a templating engine, while Backbone is a MVC like framework, used mainly for Single Page Apps. With Backbone you can manage routing, models, collections and views (using a template engine to display them!).

Comment: Backbone doesn't have a templating engine. Backbone requires underscore.js, which has a very simple [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) system included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, they do serve completely difference purposes. Moustache being a templating engine, and Backbone bringing the MVC paradigm to Javascript. To quote from the [Backbone homepage](http://backbonejs.org/)

> When working on a web application that involves a lot of JavaScript, one of the first things you learn is to stop tying your data to the DOM. It's all too easy to create JavaScript applications that end up as tangled piles of jQuery selectors and callbacks, all trying frantically to keep data in sync between the HTML UI, your JavaScript logic, and the database on your server. For rich client-side applications, a more structured approach is often helpful.

So, if you find yourself writing a load of DOM manipulation calls etc. Or you simply prefer a structured approach to your code - you will find Backbone a godsend.

It is of course possible to use other templating solutions (other than the one bundled with Underscore) and integrate it into a client-side application created with Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Both cam be use together,

To build web application architecture you can use backbonejs.

and to render templates you can use mustachejs.

First of study basic knowledge about both.
You will well understand when to use what.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)